# DRY in Rails 3 if else elsif

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Second week on RoR (with no programming background). And I have a bit of an issue, I'm doing a Metacritic type of a website. And there are going to be ratings everywhere. I decided on 0 to 33 = red 34 to 66 = orange 67 to 100 = green which looks like that

index (controller:show)

```
 <td><% if show.reviews.count == 0 %>0
    <% elsif show.reviews.average("rating").between?(33, 66) %>
    <table class="orange">
      <tr>
        <td><b><%= number_with_precision(show.reviews.average("rating"), :precision => 0) %></b></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <% elsif show.reviews.average("rating").between?(66, 100) %>
    <table class="green">
      <tr>
        <td><%= number_with_precision(show.reviews.average("rating"), :precision => 0) %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <% elsif show.reviews.average("rating").between?(00, 33) %>
    <table class="red">
      <tr>
        <td><%= number_with_precision(show.reviews.average("rating"), :precision => 0) %></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <% end %>
  </td>
```

My issue is that I'm gonna need to repeat that code, a lot, see (I'm only getting started:
show (controller show)

```
<p>
  Note: <% if @ratings == 0 %>0
  <% elsif @ratings.between?(33, 66) %>
  <table class="orange">
    <tr>
      <td><b><%= number_with_precision(@ratings, :precision => 0) %></b></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <% elsif @ratings.between?(66, 100) %>
  <table class="green">
    <tr>
      <td><%= number_with_precision(@ratings, :precision => 0) %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <% elsif @ratings.between?(00, 33) %>
  <table class="red">
    <tr>
      <td><%= number_with_precision(@ratings, :precision => 0) %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

Somebody told me this should be a model but I don't really know how to write it. Any help ?

Comment: your probably going to want to use a helper to sets the table class based on the rating.  This may help to clean up your view

Comment: can you be a little bit more specific please ? (This is my second week on Rails)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you should add an instance method to your `Show` model that retrieves and caches the average rating for a show. This prevents querying the database multiple times for the same data:

```
def average_rating
  @average_rating ||= self.reviews.average('rating')
end
```

The code that returns the appropriate css class for a `Show` can go into a helper (e.g. the `ShowHelper`):

```
module ShowHelper
  def average_rating_class_for(show)
    if show.average_rating < 34
      'red'
    elsif show.average_rating > 66
      'green'
    else
      'orange'
    end
  end
end
```

With this, your views become much cleaner:

```
<td>
<% if show.reviews.count == 0 %>
  0
<% else %>
  <table class="<%= average_rating_class_for(show) %>">
    <tr>
      <td><%= number_with_precision(show.average_rating, :precision => 0) %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<% end %>
</td>
```

And:

```
<p>
  Note:
<% if @show.reviews.count == 0 %>
  0
<% else %>
  <table class="<%= average_rating_class_for(@show) %>">
    <tr>
      <td><%= number_with_precision(@show.average_rating, :precision => 0) %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<% end %>
</p>
```

You could even move the generation of the entire table into a model. (Although you shouldn't be using a table here, but that's a different matter.)

```
module ShowHelper
  def average_rating_class_for(show)
    if show.average_rating < 34
      'red'
    elsif show.average_rating > 66
      'green'
    else
      'orange'
    end
  end

  def average_rating_table_for(show)
    if show.reviews.count == 0
      '0'
    else
      content_tag :table do
        content_tag :tr do
          contect_tag :td, :class => average_rating_class_for(show) do
            number_with_precision(show.average_rating, :precision => 0)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

With this you view becomes:

```
<td>
  <%= average_rating_table_for(show) %>
</td>
```

What Andre suggests is possible too, but it may be a bit difficult to comprehend for a beginner like yourself. This is simpler.

Comment: Without going the whole hog of a presenter, a helper is as easy as a model method and to my mind a little more appropriate than having presentation logic in the model

Comment: Hm, I guess you are right. The color is only for presentation. Let me update.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your answer. Incredible surprised by all the great feedback I get for everyone of my beginner questions.
I'll see what I most comfortable with though the code above makes sense to me (most of it anyways).

Answer (score 2):

You will need to make a new folder in your app directory called presenters.
Then you will want to create a file called rating_presenter.rb

This will be your presenter file

```
class RatingPresenter
  def initialize(rating, template)
    @rating = rating
    @template = template
  end

  def get_ratings
     # here you will house the logic to display your tables as needed
     # I would probably determine the output to return the class to set the table accordingly
     # keep in mind that view helpers are available
     # ie.  h.link_to or h.form_tag
  end

  private
    def h # we don't want to be saying @template.link_to etc everywhere, so this is a shortcut
      @template 
    end
end
```

And in the application_helper.rb file
We need to determine the class in order to present the class

```
def present(object, klass = nil)
  klass ||= "#{object.class}Presenter".constantize # assign object or nil
  presenter = klass.new(object, self)  # assign presenter to object instance
  yield presenter if block_given?  # yield if block is given
  presenter # return presenter
end
```

So in your view
You call the helper method that is then

```
<% present @rating do |rating_presenter| %>
  <p>
    <%= rating_presenter.get_ratings %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

So this is a quick and dirty example from a couple resources I've learned.  You will need to experiment/break stuff a bit to have it suit your needs.  You can expand on the `get_ratings` method and use more than one method to build your table ( this is recommended ) instead of having one method be responsible for the whole thing.  It will help you to isolate problems.  Hope this points you in the right direction

You should also search on google for "presenters +rails", you may find some more articles that will further help you understand this concept.  Finally rails has gems for handling complex view logic, check out Draper.  https://github.com/drapergem/draper

Answer (score 0):

I think for somebody "Second week on RoR (with no programming background)" using a presenter is a little out of scope. Also one should try and simplyfy step by step and only to the level one is comfortable with (no use in using constructs one does not understand)

My advise would be to simply write a small helper to decide which colour the div should be. As a first shot simply put the following method into app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
def color_for_rating(rating)
  if show.average_rating < 34
    'red'
  elsif show.average_rating > 66
    'green'
  else
    'orange'
  end
end
```

you could then clean up your index view as following by using the helper to give the correct colour for your table class

```ruby
 <td><% if show.reviews.count == 0 %>0
    <% else %>
    <table class="<%= color_for_rating(show.reviews.average("rating")) %>" >
      <tr>
        <td><b><%= number_with_precision(show.reviews.average("rating"), :precision => 0) %></b></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <% end %>
  </td>
```

As soon as you feel comfortable with this easier approach and have used it a little you can check back to investigate the more advanced solutions given in the other answers.

Comment: How does this differ from my answer?

Comment: @mischa Principally your answer is the same but you go further. For an unexperienced non programmer it can be confusing not finding a show_helper.rb to put the method into and extracting too much presentation into helpers (content_tag stuff). Also i would refrain from caching rating as it propably is not needed (yagni + ActiveRecord takes care of this).